# GCC raising an ambiguous diagnostic message

Tags: c, gcc

Whilst reading [Modern C](https://gustedt.gitlabpages.inria.fr/modern-c/), I was trying to check if GCC would raise a diagnostic message if I passed a null pointer to either of these functions:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER)
    #define ATTRIB_NONNULL(...)             __attribute__((nonnull(__VA_ARGS__)))
#else 
    #define ATTRIB_NONNULL(...)             /* If only. */
#endif

size_t my_strlen(const char *s[static 1])
{
    size_t count = 0;

    while (*s++) {
        ++count;
    }

    return count;
}

ATTRIB_NONNULL(1) size_t my_strlen1(const char *s) 
{
    size_t count = 0;

    while (*s++) {
        ++count;
    }

    return count;
}

int main(void)
{
    return my_strlen(NULL), my_strlen1(NULL);
}
```

The output it produced was this (`make null_diagnostic`):

```
null_diagnostic.c: In function ‘main’:
null_diagnostic.c:34:29: warning: argument 1 null where non-null expected [-Wnonnull]
   34 |     return my_strlen(NULL), my_strlen1(NULL);
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~
null_diagnostic.c:21:26: note: in a call to function ‘my_strlen1’ declared ‘nonnull’
   21 | ATTRIB_NONNULL(1) size_t my_strlen1(const char *s)
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~
null_diagnostic.c:34:12: warning: argument 1 to ‘const char *[static 8]’ is null where non-null expected [-Wnonnull]
   34 |     return my_strlen(NULL), my_strlen1(NULL);
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
null_diagnostic.c:10:8: note: in a call to function ‘my_strlen’
   10 | size_t my_strlen(const char *s[static 1])
      |        ^~~~~~~~~
```

It did raise diagnostic information as expected, but it speaks of passing a null pointer to a function that expected a `const char *[static 8]` instead of `const char *[static 1]`. Why does it expect the argument to be at least of length 8? What am I missing?

Here's the compiler information:

```
gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in this version of gcc, where the size of static array parameter is multiplied by the size of the element type and that is reported as the static size instead.

It looks like this was introduced in gcc 11.0 and was fixed in gcc 12.3.

https://godbolt.org/z/6sx3jPo1a

Comment: The bug was iirc about the message mixing up the number of items and the number of bytes used. Check out the bottom of [this post about `static`](https://software.codidact.com/posts/285050/285051#answer-285051) which I wrote testing with gcc 11. In one case I try to pass an int array of 4 items instead of the expected `static 5` and get a correct diagnostic "warning: 'func' accessing 20 bytes in a region of size 16". And then when I tried to pass a null pointer to the same function, weird diagnostic: "warning: argument 1 to 'int[static 20]' is null where non-null expected".